# TextInput Styling Issue - CSS - React Native

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I have a TextInput in my Native App with 2 icons - search and cancel. A cancel button to cancel the TextInput.

On clicking the TextInput a dropdown menu appears and the Filter can be chosen.

On selecting the Filter, "Hos... Aut..." text appears in the TextInput.

I do not want the text "Hospital Auth.." to come as it is. I want it to be displayed as a button in the TextInput as below

But as you can see I have alignment issues. The Placeholder, cursor and cancel button are never in the same line. It goes beyond the screen. I used FlexWrap: 'wrap' still it did not work. I tried with position 'absolute' it partially worked.

Below is my code:

```
<View style={container1}>
  <View style={section}>
    <Icon type='materialicons' name='search'/>
    <View>
      <Button icon={<Icon name="check"/>}
              type='clear' title ={val}
              onPress={()=>{this.handleFilterIcon(false)}}/>
    </View>

    <TextInput
      value={value}
      placeholder='Search Here...'
      onTouchStart={()=>{this.renderDropdown(true)}}
      style={{ height: 40, width: 290}}
      autoCapitalize='none'
      selectTextOnFocus={true}
    />

    <Icon type='materialicons' name='cancel'
          onPress={()=>{this.handleFilterIcon(false)}}/>
    <Button title='Cancel'
      buttonStyle={{backgroundColor:'#D3D3D3',
                    borderColor: 'grey', borderRadius: 6,
                    borderWidth: 1, height: 40}}
      onPress={()=>{this.renderDropdown(false)}}/>
  </View>
</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container1: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',

  },
  section: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    borderColor: '#000',
    height: 40,
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
})
```

The requirement is to get a filter like WhatsApp or gmail (not THAT advanced) but somewhat similar. When you click on the filter it should appear on the searchBar as a label/Button.

Please help me fix my code or if someone has a better idea to execute this filter please let me know!!!!

Comment: Why don't you use bootstrap rather than manually doing center align etc.

Comment: It’s a searchbar for a native app. Can we use bootstrap? If yes could you please give me the code for the above requirement?